# Convert Day to Next Available Date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

how can I convert the day to the near future date in php?

Like if I enter Monday and if today is Friday 22/08/2014 it should convert Monday to 25/08/2014 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the php function `strtotime` and the key `next week monday` to get the next date

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

```
$theDay = 'Monday'; // eg. Monday
$time = strtotime('next week ' . $theDay);
echo date('d.m.y', $time); // get next monday
```